# Extract rotated rectangle from raster in Python

Tags: geometry, gis, gdal, gdal-python-bindings

I'm using GDAL in Python to work with GeoTIFF rasters.  I use the following code to extract small rectangular patches from the entire raster:

```py
data_file = gdal.Open("path/to/raster.tiff")
data = data_file.ReadAsArray(xoffset, yoffset, xsize, ysize)
```

How could I change this code to extract **rotated rectangular areas** from the raster. For example, I would like to be able to extract data from the area shown in red below.

[image]

I'd like the red area to be resampled and rotated, so that I can access it as a simple numpy data array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution to this by following [this excellent post](https://mmas.github.io/image-affine-mapping-numpy) about how to implement affine transforms.

My solution works by:

1. Using `ReadAsArray` to read a section of the full raster that fully contains the red area;
2. Identifying points `p0`, `p1`, `p2` representing the top-left, top-right and bottom-left corners of the red area respectively in pixel coordinates;
3. Implementing the algorithm as described in the link to compute the affine transform, leaving me with the red area on its own, rotated into a horizontal position.